# Facing issues while using camel-sftp-kafka-connector in Apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, sftp, apache-kafka-connect, camel-ftp

i am trying to create a sftp connector in Apache kafka using camel-sftp-kafka-connector.

i just downloaded the sftp-connector jar and pasted into the kafka's lib folder.

while hitting /connector-plugins endpoint i can able to see the sftp-connector is available

[image: connector-plugins.img]

so below is my sample connector configuration

```
{
    "name": "camel-sftp-connector-1",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.sftp.CamelSftpSourceConnector",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
        "transforms": "RemoteTransformer",
        "transforms.RemoteTransformer.type": "org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.RemoteFileTransforms",
        "topics": "came-sftp-test-1",
        "camel.source.path.host": "192.168.30.167",
        "camel.source.path.port": "66",
        "camel.source.path.directoryName": "/csv/sample",
        "camel.source.endpoint.recursive": "true",
        "camel.source.endpoint.username": "sftpuser",
        "camel.source.endpoint.password": "sftppass",
        "camel.source.endpoint.noop": "/false",
        "camel.source.endpoint.move": "/done"
    }
}
```

I got the below exception and dont know how to fix it.

```
[2021-05-05 19:20:58,560] WARN /connectors (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel)
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jctools/queues/MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:410)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:563)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jctools/queues/MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:436)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jctools/queues/MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnectorConfig.<clinit>(CamelSourceConnectorConfig.java:43)
        at org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.sftp.CamelSftpSourceConnector.config(CamelSftpSourceConnector.java:29)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:366)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jctools.queues.MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 9 more
[2021-05-05 19:20:58,562] WARN unhandled due to prior sendError (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState)
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jctools/queues/MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:410)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:563)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jctools/queues/MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:236)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:436)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jctools/queues/MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.CamelSourceConnectorConfig.<clinit>(CamelSourceConnectorConfig.java:43)
        at org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.sftp.CamelSftpSourceConnector.config(CamelSftpSourceConnector.java:29)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:366)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$1(AbstractHerder.java:326)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jctools.queues.MessagePassingQueue$Supplier
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 9 more
```

could anyone tell me what is the issue ?

whether i am configuring in wrong way or else any extra jars need to be added?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Camel connectors, but based on the error, you'll need these jars for that specific package. There's no guarantee you'll be missing other classes needed for the connector

https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools#get-it-now

> JARs pasted into the kafka's lib folder.

Modifying the broker classpath is not the appropriate way to configure Connect's `plugin.path` setting. Connector plugin JARs should be in isolated directories per connector

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer,i will check the JCTools and come again